# How can I center 3 <ul> lists on a page?

Tags: html, css, layout, html-lists, centering

I've got 3  lists. I'm looking to center them on a page in a horizontal fashion. How can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide us with some code so we know what you've tried?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: Thank you for the helpful link. I've got my finished result posted at the bottom of this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite easy with `inline-block`:

```
#container {
    text-align: center;
}

#container ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E8LKR/)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML

```
<div id="navcontainer">
    <ul id="navlist">
    <li id="active"><a href="#">Item one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
    </ul>

        <ul id="navlist">
    <li id="active"><a href="#">Item one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
    </ul>

        <ul id="navlist">
    <li id="active"><a href="#">Item one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

The CSS

```
#navcontainer
{
    width: 300px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
#navlist li
{
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding-right: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E25VX/1/

Comment: Thank you! Another good method.

Comment: Thor, do you want vertical lists organize horizontally? or horizontal lists?

Comment: I'm looking for the lists to be ordered horizontally. And I want them to be centered on the page, but I want all the text from each list to be positioned to the left. Got it now, thank you! :)

Comment: If you got it then good luck, not sure I understood what you wanted

Comment: This is what I was trying to do. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/fxP7c/